# celery task fails with dlib cnn face detection

Tags: python, celery, dlib

I have flask app with following extensions used:

```
Python 3.7.2
Flask 1.0.2
Celery 4.3.0rc2
dlib 19.6
```

Without celery, as a regular single-thread program for face detection, everything works fine, but when I'm starting it as a task - the following error occurs:

> Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely:
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV).')

on this piece of code:

```
dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(model)
```

And I don't get why, but with this:

```
dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
```

it works fine!

I know the conflict caused by `dlib` (or `BLAS`) not being thread-safe, but is there any way to disable multiprocessing either make celery workers work with this?

**UPD**:
I have following project structure:

```
./app/face_detector.py
./tasks.py
```

In `tasks.py` I'm using this on top of the file:

`from app.face_detector import FaceDetector`

the trick with import inside of task:

```
@app.task
def foo():
    from app.face_detector import FaceDetector
```

Doesn't work at all and throws this:

> no module named...

So, the solution from github thread was not understood by me or not working

Comment: I had a similar problem and I tried importing it inline in the task as [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2964) thread suggested, it worked for me

Comment: @Mntfr I've seen this thread, didn't get `import theano` thing though (if you've meant this), could you explain in more detail? I'd appreciate your example of before/after even

Comment: theano is a deeplearning lib as dlib, so it say you can import dlib... in the subprocess and don't import in parent module.